# javascript won't execute when back button is used

Tags: javascript

I have the following in a .js file

```
$.ajax({ cache: false, url: "/marble/ping?randomString=" + new Date().getTime() });
```

Steps to replicate problem

1. Navigate to page where the js file is included
2. Navigate to a different page
3. Use back button to go back to the previous page and the javascript doesn't execute again

Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: Can you post the code for the back button?

Comment: @TommyO I think he means the browser's back button...

Comment: as in the back button in the browser window

Comment: I guess it's a client cache issue in the browser.  The .js file is not being executed.  Try adding a random string to the src of the script tag which includes the file.

Comment: Are you invoking the function on page reload?

Comment: Ah gotcha, my bad. I thought you meant you had a `<button>` or `<input type="button">` that was handling the event.